# Core Data multiple context sync

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In my App I have shared PersistentStoreCoordiantor and few separate managedObjectContexts. Each of them could to change data. After making changes I perform save operation and all changes are saved in main thread.

Question: do all contexts synchronize after saving in main thread? If no, how to synchronize data in each context?

Answer (score 4):

Your managed object context objects should listen for the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` to be notified when any context performs a save. When that occurs, you need each managed object context to call `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` with the notification that is posted from saving. This will merge all saved changed from one MOC to all of your others.

Answer (score 1):

No, they don't. Imagine some other context saving changes to an object you're working on right now. If you want to update your context and revert your changes your can use the `reset` method.

Comment: Using `reset` is almost always way, way too drastic.